# SP2010 Add/Update multi-select lookup column REST

Tags: 2010, rest, jquery, multiple-values, multi-select

I have a list named CAG_QUESTION with a multi select lookup column to a list named CAG_REFERENCES. I have been unable to get an update to work that includes the lookup column. I thought I needed to pass an array of the CAG_REFERENCES Ids.

Here is the code I have.

```
var itemProperties = {
    ReferenceLookup: {
        results: [{
                "__metadata": { type: "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.CAG_REFERENCESItem" },
                Id: 33
            },
            {
                "__metadata": { type: "Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.CAG_REFERENCESItem" },
                Id: 23
            }]
    }
};


updateListItem(myWebUrl(), "CAG_QUESTION", 184, itemProperties,
    function() {
        console.log('Success Guardian ... Success.');
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

It fails with a payload must represent a valid array format for collections error.

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\r\n\"error\": {\r\n\"code\": \"\", \"message\": {\r\n\"lang\": \"en-US\", \"value\": \"Error processing request stream. The payload must represent a valid array format for collections.\"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sad this was never answered here. But for the lurkers here it is.

**Adding selections to a multivalue lookup field using REST**

Here's the necessary format for your data payload:

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
    MultiLookupColumnName:[
        { 
            __metadata: { 
                uri: "http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(1)"
            }
        },
         { 
            __metadata: { 
                uri: "http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(2)"
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

This example assumes that your lookup column is named `MultiLookupColumnName`, that the list that your lookup column is looking up against is entitled `LookupListName`, and that you want to set your multi-lookup field to lookup to the items with IDs 1 and 2.

In your code, you would use that `data` variable in place of your `itemProperties` variable.

For the sake of completeness, here's a full example without jQuery:

```
var idOfItemToUpdate = 1;
var url = "/serverRelativeUrl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourListName("+idOfItemToUpdate+")"
var data = JSON.stringify({
    MultiLookupColumnName:[
        {__metadata:{uri:"http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(1)"}},
        {__metadata:{uri:"http://yoursiteurl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/LookupListName(2)"}}
    ]
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST",url,true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
xhr.setRequestHeader("If-Match", "*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(data);
```

**Removing selections from a multivalue lookup field using REST**

Note that to remove a value from the multi-selection lookup field, you'll need to use a different operation. The above operation only adds to the selected values.

To remove a selected value from the field, use a `DELETE` operation like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("DELETE",
    "/serverRelativeUrl/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourListName(1)/$links/MultiLookupColumnName(2)",
    true);
xhr.send();
```

That code would remove the lookup value with an item ID of 2 from the field named `MultiLookupColumnName` on the item with an ID of 1 on the list named `YourListName`.

(Can you diagram that sentence?)

**Footnote: Callback functions without jQuery**

I used `XMLHttpRequest` for the above examples, but I don't want that to cause you any headaches down the road.

If you decide to use the built-in `XMLHttpRequest` instead of a jQuery/AJAX wrapper, you can use its `onreadystatechange` event and pass it a callback function like so:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        myCallbackFunction(xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
    }
};

function myCallbackFunction(status, text){
    // decide what to do based on the status
}
```

This answer brought over from [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277825/updating-a-multi-select-lookup-column-rest) where it was answered by [Thriggle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2701677/thriggle)